# Find a discontinuous function defined on $\mathbb{Q}$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: examples-counterexamples, continuity

I am reading Chapter 1 Example 11 of 'Counterexamples in Analysis' by Gelbaum and Olmstead. This section illustrates counterexamples of functions defined on $\mathbb{Q}$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}$ of statements that are usually true for functions defined on a real domain. Almost all examples have the assumption that the function (defined on a rational domain) is continuous, for example, the book gives a counterexample of:

> A function continuous and bounded on a closed interval but not
>   uniformly continuous.

My questions are, what is an example of a discontinuous real function defined on $\mathbb{Q}$, that is: $f:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$? Are all functions defined on $\mathbb{Q}$ discontinuous (similar to how functions defined on the set of natural numbers are always continuous)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1). All functions defined on $\mathbb{N}$ are continuous (not discontinuous).

2). An example of a function $f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is discontinuous is $f = \chi_{\{0\}}$, i.e. $f(x) = 1$ iff $x = 0$ ($x \in \mathbb{Q}$). One can see that this is discontinuous by noting that $f(\frac{1}{n}) = 0$ for each $n \ge 1$, while $f(\lim_n \frac{1}{n}) = f(0) = 1$.

Comment: Regarding your first point, yes, that is what I meant to say, I edited my question accordingly. Secondly, thank you for your counterexample...what is "special" about the natural numbers that makes all function continuous and not the rationals? Is it that $\mathbb{N}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$ while $\mathbb{Q}$ is?

Comment: It's because the topology on $\Bbb N$ is **discrete**. @DylanZammit

Comment: It has nothing to do with $\mathbb{N}$'s or $\mathbb{Q}$'s relation to $\mathbb{R}$. Indeed, any function $f: \mathbb{N} \to X$ for any topological space $X$ is continuous. This is because $\mathbb{N}$ has only isolated points. The fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not like this is exactly what allowed me to give that counterexample I gave.